# How to print the first letter of a string, then the first and second, etc

Tags: python, string

I am trying to print a "triangle" if you will, with the letters in a string. If I have the word "right" the output should be something like

```
r
ri
rig
righ
right
```

I am aware that you loop through the string with a for loop without indices

```
for i in string:
    print(i)
```

or with indices

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    print(string[i])
```

but I'm not sure how I would add each letter onto the next line.

Comment: Look up "slices": You can extract more than one letter at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you index, so you print the character on the `i`-th index. You can use [***slicing*** [Pythoncentral]](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) to generate the list to (and perhaps including) `i`. For example:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    print(string[:i+1])
```

Notice the colon here, it means that we slice the string up to (but without) the `i`-th index. So `string[:4]`, will generate a list up to (but without) index `4`. So the string will have length `4`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using [slicing](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings#string-slices) and the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) builtin:

```
for index, c in enumerate(your_string, 1):
    print(your_string[:index])
```

`enumerate` generates pairs of indexes and elements. Example:

```
>>> for i, c in enumerate('hello', 1):
        print(i, c)
1 h
2 e
3 l
4 l
5 o
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'right'
for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
    print(s[:i])
```

s[:1] means that you print all the characters in s from start to